# Hook for plugin to insert into entry-meta

Tags: plugins, hooks, footer, headers

pretty simple. I'm creating a plugin and I want to dynamically insert some text that will change every hour into the line that is directly below the title of a post (So filters are no good). It's the `<div class="entry-meta">`. The `<div class="entry-utility">` at the bottom of the post would be good too. I can't seem to find a hook for this and I'm guessing there is none.

Right now the solution I have is to hook into "the_content" and place it as a footer, but it looks reaaally bad because it's a small piece of text with an entire line to itself. It would look considerably better if I could insert it into those lines mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines you mention are most likely part of your theme.

You will need to either:

- figure out which functions/templates output them and if they have hooks to use;
- edit theme (create child theme) to add your own function to output what you want.

Comment: Crap, I didn't want the plugin to become a theme : / Doesn't that run the risk of colliding with other themes?

Comment: @Thirlan essentially yes. If you want to release such functionality as public plugin you should probably provide template tag function that others can insert in their theme. There isn't really any clean way to insert something at arbitrary point without hooks available.